# disabling anonymous ftp on windows 2003 server enables unencrypted passwords

Tags: windows-server-2003, ftp

While doing some web development work on a website for a client I realised that their server (windows 2003 VM) has Anonymous ftp enabled. This is not something they want.

I'm attempting to turn it off for them as follows:

under

```
IIS Manager -> FTP Sites -> Properties  -> Security Accounts
```

there is a checkbox `Allow anonymous connections` which I assume I need to uncheck. BUT when I uncheck it the following warning message appears:

```
The authentication option you have selected results in passwords being transmitted over the network without data encryption. Someone attempting to compromise your system security could use a protocol analyzer to examine user passwords during the authentication process. For more detail on user authentication, consult the online help. This warning does not apply to HTTPS (or SSL) connections.
```

now, that doesn't sound like something I want either.

Is this my only option - disable anonymous ftp but enable unencrypted passwords - or is the unencrypted passwords not a relevant issue?

I am a developer and I usually work in linux environments so I'm a bit out of my depth here on two counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's warning you because you're using FTP in general, which is plaintext. Disabling anonymous connections would then require a username/password pair, which is what Windows is complaining about. It's safe to do (although FTP in general isn't "safe").

Comment: Well its not that safe to do since anyone can sniff your passwords!

Comment: Anyone with access to your network, that is. Someone can't just say "I want all the traffic going to this host" and grab it.

Comment: ah ok, so FTP is always plaintext and making this change does not make ftp any more insecure than usual. thank you - that's exactly what i wanted to know.

Comment: The reason it is a problem is because your windows passwords are normally encrypted.  By using those accounts over ftp you are exposing the details which someone can use to log onto the more secure services.

Comment: The question wasn't about the security of FTP but rather why it was tossing the warning. The warning is because FTP is being used to begin with.

Comment: @NathanC or anywhere in between if they connect across the internet without a vpn, or anyone on wifi, or trojan/keylogger

Comment: @NathanC the warning is because you are exposing AD accounts not just an FTP session.  FTP in IIS7 allows you to use seperate accounts.

Comment: Then they have more to worry about. Again, this question is *not* about the security of FTP. Anyone who uses it accepts the risk it has (like telnet). Also, FTP accounts and AD accounts are not always one and the same. You can restrict AD signon and just use dedicated FTP accounts.

Comment: @NathanC if they know the risk, the warning is telling them it!  Stop being pedantic and see the big picture.